# Slick slider - add new item to center

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I am using a slick slider with center mode, I want to add more slides on click of "add" button. My concern is how can I add this new div to 'center' (element which is on focus in center mode) instead of the last item.

```
$('.add').on('click', function() {
    $('.slider').slick('slickAdd','<div>test</div>');
});
```

Now its adding new element to the last position. (I want this item as the centered item every time when I add new item)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I verified the below code and it works fine hope it works you as well

```
$('.slider').slick('slickAdd','<div>test</div>', $('.slider').slick('slickCurrentSlide')-1);
```